# Create Bitmap from Canvas with fixed resolution & device independent

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, android-canvas

I would like to create Bitmap dynamically which will be saved to file and used later as Instagram Story.
Bitmap suppose to have fixed resolution 1080x1920 and be independent from current device.

On this bitmap I would like to put downloaded image and some text. So it will be something like this:

```kotlin
val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1080, 1920, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)

val imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("local-file.jpg")
val scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, 1080, 1080, true)
canvas.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, null, Rect(0, 0, 1080, 1080), null)
canvas.save()

val textPaint = TextPaint()
textPaint.textSize = 32f
textPaint.isAntiAlias = true

var loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do..."
var staticLayout = StaticLayout.Builder.obtain(
        loremIpsum, 0, loremIpsum.length, textPaint, 600).build()
canvas.translate(240f, 1200f);
staticLayout.draw(canvas)

canvas.restore()
canvas.save()

// bitmap.compress(...)
```

So how to achieve such effect, to be device independent?
I would like always produce output image with constant sizes of nested images and text.

---

After further investigation (I used device file explorer) it looks like that images are saved correctly to the filesystem, but after this something is broken when sharing to Instagram. Maybe Instagram downscales it somehow base on device resolution...

Comment: Nothing in that code snippet seems to be tied to the device. What specific problems have you encountered with that code?

Comment: When I produce the same story from diffrent Android device it looks differently. For instance from Samsung Galaxy S9 is sharp and looks natural. From Samsung Galaxy J3 images and texts are bigger and more blurry. It looks like density is used somehow. I compare it just as results in story so it is easy to see differences.

Comment: Can you drop those pictures here? so that we can see what's wrong with it?

Comment: Unfortunately I can’t upload those photos right now. It looks like the issue is density. Density is set automatically for canvas and bitmap. I tried to override those values with for instance DENSITY_NONE constant but it didn’t help.

So in general with low res device particular elements are more sharpen and blurry. With high res device they are more accurate.